# How do I compare items in list in Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays

What should I put in If Block so it can compare the two items? I mean that I want to open the France activity when I clicked on the France list item and when I clicked on it work but when searching another country for example US , so it filters the US and US display on top and when I clicked on the US it opens the France activity. so I wanted sth like that in the if statement it Compares France list item to the First list item on the list if it is France, it opens the France Activity!

```
SearchView searchView;
    ListView listView;

    String[] list = {"France","United States","Spain","China","Italy","United Kingdom","Germany","Mexico","Thailand","Turkey","Austria",
            "Malaysia","Hong Kong","Greece","Russia","Japan","Canada","Saudi Arabia","Poland","South Korea","Netherlands"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        searchView  = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.search_View);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.search_list);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                 if(What should put here?){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),France.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your ListView's item position:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                 String str = listView.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString();
                    if ( str.equals("France")) {
                        showToast("France clicked");
                    }
            }
        });

private void showToast(String str) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

You can also use `else if` for other strings.